# Wiredep a bower component with glob patterns in main

Tags: wiredep, grunt-wiredep

I am using a bower component which has glob patterns specified for its css and scss files in its bower.json -> main array

```
"main": [
    "dist/css/**/*.css",
    "dist/sass/**/*.scss",
    "dist/scripts/component.js"
]
```

When I run grunt wiredep task the following is what gets injected in the HTML file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/custom_component/dist/css/**/*.css" />
```

I have looked into the overrides configuration of wiredep and it works fine.

```
"overrides": {
     "custom_component": {
     "main": ["dist/css/help.css"]
    }
 }
```

My problem is that we are hard-coding a file path that we have no control over. Is there a way to make wiredep find the file-paths from the glob patterns and inject them accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is facing the same issue, here is the solution.

Check your grunt-wiredep version. If it is not 2.0.0 or later then change the version (^2.0.0) and that's it. This should solve the problem.

In my case I was using grunt-wiredep version 1.9.0 which internally used wiredep 1.8.6.